# What attribuites are included in filesystem metadata for docker COPY instruction?

Tags: docker

From the documentation:

> COPY obeys the following rules:
>
> The `<src>` path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot `COPY ../something /something`, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.
>
> If `<src>` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.

Does anyone know what attributes are included in the filesystem metadata?

note: this is causing intermediate layer cache invalidation for me and I want to figure out what exactly is the root cause of it. Thanks.

Comment: So are you saying anytime you build the image, it always starts from your COPY step?

Comment: Not every time. The first time I built locally on my computer and push the image. The second time I build inside a CI environment where the username and timestamps are different. In this case docker re-uses the previous layers but starts from the COPY step although the content is exactly the came. Then the latest image from CI gets pushed to docker hub and on the third time I build in CI docker reuses all previous layers.